# ¿Como Cambiar BackColor de Celda en DataGridView?

Tags: c#

Tengo este arreglo :

```
 Color[] colores = { System.Drawing.Color.White,
                     System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke,
                     System.Drawing.Color.Yellow };
```

y por otro lado, tengo un DataGridView que siempre contendrá igual numero de filas  como elementos el arreglo colores. lo que nesecito es cambiar es el color de las celdas de la primera columna llamada Color por su respectivo en el arreglo... algo así:

```
  COLOR                  NOMBRE                                     

BackGround White          WHITE                         

BackGround WhiteSmoke     WHITESMOKE                      

BackGround Yellow         YELLOW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asi lo hace perfectamente

```
   Color[] colores = {
            System.Drawing.Color.White , System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke, System.Drawing.Color.DimGray,
            System.Drawing.Color.Gray, System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray,  System.Drawing.Color.Silver, System.Drawing.Color.LightGray,
            System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro, System.Drawing.Color.Maroon,  System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed, System.Drawing.Color.Red,
            System.Drawing.Color.Brown, System.Drawing.Color.Firebrick,System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed, System.Drawing.Color.Snow,
            System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral, System.Drawing.Color.RosyBrown,System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose, System.Drawing.Color.Salmon,
            System.Drawing.Color.Tomato, System.Drawing.Color.DarkSalmon,System.Drawing.Color.Coral, System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed,
            System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon,System.Drawing.Color.Sienna, System.Drawing.Color.SeaShell, System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate,
            System.Drawing.Color.SaddleBrown, System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown, System.Drawing.Color.PeachPuff, System.Drawing.Color.Peru,
            System.Drawing.Color.Linen, System.Drawing.Color.Bisque, System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange, System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood,
            System.Drawing.Color.Tan, System.Drawing.Color.AntiqueWhite,System.Drawing.Color.NavajoWhite, System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond,
            System.Drawing.Color.PapayaWhip, System.Drawing.Color.Moccasin,  System.Drawing.Color.Orange, System.Drawing.Color.Wheat,
            System.Drawing.Color.OldLace,
        };
 private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.DataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Color")
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = colores[e.RowIndex];  
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu pregunta no mencionas que tengas una COLUMNA llamada `Color`...

Answer (score 2):

> Código modificado de esta [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27525198/4092887) en Stack Overflow *en inglés*:

---

Una opción puede ser la siguiente:

```
int colorIncr = 0; // Este valor se usará para intercambiar los colores.

// Recorre las filas de tu DataGridView.
for (int i = 0; i < dtgv1.Rows.Count)
{
    // Establecer color a la fila.
    dtgv1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = colores[colorIncr];

    // Verificar que valor de incremento no sea mayor la
    // cantidad de datos del arreglo de colores.
    if (colorIncr >= colores.Length)
    {
       // Valor original.
       colorIncr = 0;
    }
}
```